# Use the generated Session ID of website to fetch an ID of that external system through Apex class

Tags: json, httprequest, httpresponse

I have below HttpRequest POST code where I can get in debug log the response from external system.

I can see my required Session ID that needs to be used as Authorization to fetch further data from that system.

Can someone please let me know how to store that Session ID value in a string?

**My Code in developer console**

```
HTTP auth = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
    r.setEndpoint('https://XXXX.veevavault.com/api/v17.1/auth?');
    String jsonBody ='username=*****&password=****';
    r.setBody(jsonBody);
    r.setMethod('POST');   
    r.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    HTTPResponse authresp=new HttpResponse();
    authresp = auth.send(r); 

system.debug('authresp@'+authresp.getBody());
```

Response returned as below :

```
authresp@{"responseStatus":"SUCCESS","sessionId":"XXXXX","userId":XXXX,"vaultIds":[{"id":XXXX,"name":"XXXXX","url":"https://XXXXXX-XXX.com/api"}],"vaultId":XXXX}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to deserialize the response and then get the key

```
Map<String,object> responseMap =(Map<String,object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(authresp.getBody()) ;  
String token =  String.valueOf(responseMap.get('sessionId'));
```

You can use `JSON.deserializeUntyped` to deserialize it into map of string object and then using key you can get the value. Code sample for your reference.

Complete Code

```
HTTP auth = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
    r.setEndpoint('https://sb-abbvie-ae.veevavault.com/api/v17.1/auth?');
    String jsonBody ='username=*****&password=****';
    r.setBody(jsonBody);
    r.setMethod('POST');   
    r.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    HTTPResponse authresp=new HttpResponse();
    authresp = auth.send(r); 
Map<String,object> responseMap =(Map<String,object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(authresp.getBody()) ;  
String token =  String.valueOf(responseMap.get('sessionId'));
System.debug(token);
```

> **Note:** Also never share your credentials in public forum.

Comment: Please find my edited endpoint URL and update